# Getting an error while trying to use webhooks for jenkins that is in aws for bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, webhooks, bitbucket-server

This is the error while im trying to trigger webhook from bitbucket for jenkins that was placed in AWS :-

**Unable to connect to the URL specified within the timeout, please check the host and port are correct and that the URL is accessible from the server running this request.**

and this Request details :-

Event type:repo:refs_changed
URL endpoint:http://awsipaddress:portnumber/bitbucket-server-webhook/trigger
Headers
X-Request-Id: 9ba55d7f-2eb9-4daa-b143-82098889af68
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Event-Key: repo:refs_changed

and the particular port is available for in inbound and outbound rules too ....